# What does scripts "npm run dev" and "npm run watch" is used for?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm new in vue, and a documentation says that every time I create a component I have to run `npm run dev` and `npm run watch`.
But don't know what their purpose is?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Technically those will just run whatever scripts are defined in your `package.json` with the name `dev` and `watch`. Without seeing your `package.json` it's impossible to know exactly what they do.

For most project configurations those commands will compile your Vue components into raw javascript. The difference between dev and watch is the `dev` command will compile the code then exit while the `watch` command will compile the components then watch the files and recompile when one of them changes.

Comment: When writing ‚run‘ in last sentence you probably refer to ,dev’ as both commands contain ‘run’?

Comment: @SimonThiel Correct, thanks. I've updated my answer. In the command `npm run watch` *npm* is the package manager, *run* is a specific command for the package manager to execute, and *dev* an the argument for the command. In this case it is telling *npm* to *run* the script called *dev/watch*.

Answer (score 30):

`npm run dev` combines all your Vue components and other JavaScript files into a browser-friendly combined file.

`npm run watch` does the same, but then it stays active and "watches" for updates to your `.vue` and `.js` files. If it detects a change, it'll re-build the browser-friendly file so you can just refresh the page.