# my tailwind didnt update class after i change file

Tags: css, tailwind-css

my file
https://github.com/EndPx/error.git
when i do "npm run build", it was working to rebuild but it work just one time. i need to restart server npx to rebuiding again, it is very disturbing

Rebuilding...

Done in 212ms.

i need to know too its normal if done in 212ms?

I've done the other suggestions but it doesn't work

i want to my npx can rebuild automatic without need to restart server at all times

Comment: See [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720485/what-does-scripts-npm-run-dev-and-npm-run-watch-is-used-for)

Answer (score 0):

### Your output.css file is not referenced correctly.

You got two options:

first option in package.json to change the build command to output.css in the right place -

```
"build": "npx tailwindcss --watch -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css"
```

and in index.html -

```
<link href="output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

second option in to change the refernced place in index.html -

```
<link href="../output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you want to see the changes afterwards you need to refresh the page. There is an extension that called - Live Server (for VSCode) that refreshing the page automatically on any change in the code.

There is also a lot of solutions for other code editors.